# MvvmCross MvxApplication unable to register types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, mvvmcross

This is the content of my App.cs which inherits from Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication.

```
 public class App : Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            CreatableTypes()
               .EndingWith("Repository")
               .AsInterfaces()
               .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            CreatableTypes()
              .EndingWith("Factory")
              .AsInterfaces()
              .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Mapper")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            RegisterAppStart<FirstViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

This is defined in my Core project and works fine with the Android application project.  This project was created using Visual Studio 2012 and all dependencies added using NuGet.

The same Core project on a Windows Phone 7.5 version of the application throws the following exceptions after running each of the CreatableTypes() statement:

```
mvx:Warning:  6.56 ReflectionTypeLoadException masked during loading of TrackuTransit.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null - error ReflectionTypeLoadException: ReflectionTypeLoadException
       at System.Reflection.Module.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions.ExceptionSafeGetTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions.CreatableTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication.CreatableTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication.CreatableTypes()
   at TrackuTransit.Core.App.Initialize()
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.Cr
```

For WP7.1, I had to add dependencies to MvvmCross version 3.0.13 manually as MvvmCross NuGet is currently at 3.1.1 and does not appear to be compatible with Visual Studio 2010.  These are Droid project dependencies:

[image: Droid project dependencies]

and these are the WP7.1 dependencies:

[image: Windows 7.5 dependencies]

These exceptions are preventing framework from resolving constructor parameters for FirstViewModel.

```
  public class FirstViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly Profile _profile;

        public FirstViewModel(IProfileService profileService, IMvxMessenger messenger)
            : base(profileService, messenger)
        {
            _profile = profileService.GetProfile();
        }
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.0.14 was the last MvvmCross version to support VS2010 and WP7

3.1.1 supports VS2012 and later, and WP8, Win8, WPF4.5, Xam.Android and Xam.iOS (and SL50 - but only with some work from users!)

The reason for this is because Microsoft VS2013 no longer supports WP7 and the PCL functionality and libraries they released for cross-platform use (e.g. with Xamarin) do not include the older profiles like 104 - so they do not support WP7.

This change was announced July 2013 - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/mvvmcross-wp7-tombstoned.html - but actually we held off implementing as long as we could - so it didn't actually happen until Feb 2014

3.0.14 is available via the nuget command line and is a good stable release - it's been used in many apps - but it's not likely to be actively supported and revised in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have upgraded to v3.0.14 but still get the same exceptions in the output window.  Anything else I should be looking out for?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Still running into same exception but suspecting a problem with my dependencies.  What is the NuGet package id for assembly Cirrious.CrossCore that needs to be referenced in my core project?  I have upgraded all of the packages in my core project but missing Cirrious.CrossCore in my core project.

Comment: Stuart, think what I need to do is clear all the MvvmCross dependencies and install the MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack.  Tried this on a clean project and it pulls in Cirrious.CrossCore.

Comment: Clean and rebuild should do it for you. Nuget is pretty good at removing the .csproj level dependencies, but Visual Studio can still hang on to the assemblies in the /bin folders

Comment: Appears as though my problem is coming from Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WindowsPhone v3.0.14.  I run into the same problem on a new clean VS2010 Windows Phone project when attempting to use this plugin.  When I look at the MvvmCross source in VS2012 the Windows Phone File plugin project is not available.  Does the mean Windows Phone file plugin works only with Windows 8?